# Why does water collect under a book my laptop is sitting on?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, water

Sometimes I sit in my bed with a blanket over my lap. On top of the blanket I put a hardcover book. On top of the book I will be working on my laptop. So we've got:

Laptop

Book

Blanket

My lap

Sometimes after being on my laptop for a time I lift up the book and there will be water on the underside of the book. It doesn't happen every time, but it does often. The water is on the book, the blanket is dry. I am not sweaty, I live in Utah, a dessert, so it is usually not humid.

I am sure the water is condensation, and the heat of the laptop plays a part, but I do not understand exactly what is going on to cause this to happen.

If someone can explain the physical process going on here I would appreciate the gain in knowledge!

Comment: This might be more applicable to Physics than Earth Science. The only association with earth science is the atmosphere plays role in what is happening. My thoughts are, the hotter the air, the more water vapor it can hold. This is where the hot air vent from the laptop has a role. When it occurs the air might be more humid than usual, or the water is emerging from your skin. Do your thighs perspire when this happens? The underside of the book may be sheltered from the hot laptop vent allowing vapor to condense on the cooler side of the book.

Comment: Agree that it's probably just a general physics question.  But not sure I'm convinced it's anything more than a misleading feeling (many sensations can feel like water), or previously sweating when the fan is sending out heat, then stopping.

Comment: The moisture must be coming from your body, there's no other source, nor an extra cold location to condense moisture. Warm air can hold more moisture and can evaporate  more, but that won't rapidly cool on something like a book. This is limited moisture from your body, not a copious amount of moisture like a tea kettle has, and the heating is limited and more indirect, even if concentrated by covering most of the vents. The blanket is dry because it can absorb some without feeling moist. Based upon covering with a book and blanket... not sure it has anything to do with laptop heat even.

Comment: Your leg, the blanket, and the book are compressed together by the laptop, so they should basically share similar levels of moisture (coming from your leg that can't release its heat causing it to sweat.  Water wouldn't sit on the bottom of the book and not transfer to the blanket/your body.  The only difference is the blanket can absorb a bit (and not be noticeably wet), and your skin can too, while any moisture on the book stays on the surface of the book completely (assuming it's some sort of laminated cover or such, like a typical big book like a textbook or encyclopedia I'd use should be)

Comment: You need to repeat this "experiment" with different setups:  no book,  then no laptop, then some large flat object in place of the laptop but not putting out any power (heat).  The other thing you need to quantify is the available airflow at each interface.  It appears the blanket "sags" to allow a channel under the book, for example?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes due to the space between my legs the blanket does droop some underneath the book so there is an air channel under there.